# Node - Image sent from React is empty {}

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, upload

I have the following input in React.js:

```
<input onChange={this.handleChange("file")} type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"/>
```

My onSubmit method method then performs a post request to node as such:

```
onSubmit(state) {
    let image = document.getElementById("fileToUpload").files[0];
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            // 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'name': this.state.name,
            'meta' : this.state.metaData,
            'id': this.state.buildingId,
            'location': this.state.location,
            'image': image
        })
    })
}
```

Now in node, if i log out in express req.body.image. I just get an empty {}.

What is wrong with the file upload process?

Thanks

Update:

I have these body parsers:

```
app.use( bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}) );
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit:50000
}));
```

I also have:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {

        console.log('sent');
        console.log(req.body);
    })
```

I now get the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: You could try using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instead of sending JSON. `const formData = new FormData(); formData.append('image', image); ... ;  fetch('http://localhost:4000/upload', formData);`

Comment: Please see my update. I sent using your method